How to pass callback data to flask route function?
I wan't to pass data to a route function, when registering the callback.
def foo (bar):
    print (bar)

app.add_url_rule ("/", "foo", foo)

How can I pass data directly to bar (i.e. without a lambda)?
PS: Ideally the function should belong to a class, but this should be achievable once I can pass parameters.

This question is similar to: Python: Build Route Handlers Programatically. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you don't want to use a lambda expression, you can still use partial(). The procedure should be identical to using lambda.

@Detlef Yes, exactly. It works the same way, which I don't like. I don't want to encapsulate it.

You could do this by setting a default value app.add_url_rule ("/", "foo", foo, defaults={“bar”: “yourvaluehere”}).

@EAW Thank you. Can you write an answer, with this approach?
